# How to loop gridviews for each database row?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am developing an asp.net web form application that displays some info on separate gridviews based on parameters. The second gridview depends of the values in the first one (Salida and Llegada, they work as a time range). This works only when the data displayed on the first GV has just one row.

This is how it works:

[image: Current Display]

But, is there a way to loop the same gridviews for each row stored in the database? something like this:

[image: Desired Display]

Or maybe there is an easier option I haven't considered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that for each row on gridview1 you want to fetch data and generate a gridview2

Comment: @yahya kh, Yes, but I want to display only one row at a time in gridview1. And then show it's corresponding info on gridview2. After that, a repetition of gridview1 will display the next data row below gridview2 and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it should be simple, first sit your gridview1 paging to fetch only view only one record, Then after you fill your gridview1 i assume that you have putten an ID either as Datakeys or what ever method you have used, the index of the row should be 0 since it's always viewing one row only. Get your id and fetch your data and bind it the second gridview2.

After that on the Gridview1_Paging event you bind your data again and the use the same method above to fetch the data for the next record.

Comment: That's a great way to do that, thanks. However, I'm struggling a little bit when retrieving the cell values. I'm using "string salida = gridview.Rows[0].Cells[7].ToString();" and it's not getting any string value, instead, the value is salida="System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell" when debugging.

Comment: Replaced ".ToString()" with ".Text" and it's working now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit clunky, but the simplest option may be to add GV1 and GV2 to a repeater.  Each row of the repeater would essentially be the data source for your GV1.

Comment: Do you have any examples? It sounds pretty logical, but I don't know how to apply it.